# Local kubectl connectivity to remote minikube hosted on vagrant

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, kubectl, minikube

My use case is to use local kubectl utility to manage remote minikube cluster hosted on vagrant VM.

My local side is under Windows platform (IP : 192.168.1.129) and use Vagrant/VirtualBox to provision a VM with Virtualbox network type of both NAT and Bridge Adapter. The VM (dual NIC with IPs 192.168.1.100 and 172.17.0.1) installed with minikube cluster (IP : 172.17.0.2). Now I like to configure local ~/.kube/config to manage such remote minibus, please advise how to make it work.

Sample of ~/.kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://192.168.1.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: c:/Users/xx/.kube/client.crt
    client-key: c:/Users/xx/.kube/client.key
```

Answer (score 0):

In resume, you'll need to configure the `kubectl` to access your remote machine running minikube. Basically copying the certificates and configuring the `./kube/config`.

Also, you will need to start the minikube using the flag `--apiserver-ips`:

> A set of apiserver IP Addresses which are used in the generated certificate for kubernetes.  This can be used if you want to make the apiserver available from outside the machine (default [])

There are some interesting articles that can guid you through this, for example:

[Remote access to minikube with kubectl](https://www.systemcodegeeks.com/devops/remote-access-to-minikube-with-kubectl/)

[Access minikube using kubectl from remote machine](https://medium.com/@kuljeetsinghkhurana/access-minikube-using-kubectl-from-remote-machine-2b0eeefad9cb0)

References:

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/